# s3 getdata is not returning anything on Alexa-Hosted(Node Js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to create an Alexa Skill on the Alexa Developer Console (using Alexa Hosted) and I want to recover a file from the bucket.

I created the file successfully, but when I try to recover it is not returning anything and I don't see any kind of error in the logs.

That's my code:

```
async function getGameData(key)
{
    const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET,
        Key: key
    };
    const respose = await S3.getObject(params, (err => {
        if(err) {
            console.log('Error recovering the file')
        }
    }))
    return respose.Body;
}
```

and there are my logs:
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63tug.png)

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the AWS SDK for Javascript, `S3.getObject` does not return a promise. You must use `.promise()`.

```
let response;
try {
    response = await S3.getObject(params).promise();
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Error recovering the file');
}
```